# Solr performance for dismax field boosting vs payload boosting

Tags: performance, solr, lucene, benchmarking

If I do want increase performance of my multi-field keyword solr index.
Which option should work faster:

1. Multifield index and dismax per field boosting
2. Single field index with additional information per token using payload. Custom Similarity to apply same boosting as in Dismax Solr Parser

Are there any benchmarks on described options?

Comment: These solutions don't look equivalent to me given that the IDF will have different values.

Comment: Payload value modifies original score which contains idf,tf factor and others.